# How to change the vruler font size and how to hide the particular page

Tags: rules, endnotes

I am using the **`vruler` package** for creating the **line numbers**. My need is to adjust the **`vruler` fontsize slightly big**. I don't know how to adjust the vruler font size.

The second thing is I am creating the **author queries** using the package `endnotes`. The endnote is printed beginning of the document. My need is the vruler should be hide on the printing endnote page and the vruler counting number is started "0001" on chapter opening page.

MWE

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{vruler}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\theendnotes}\newpage
\setvruler[10pt][1][1][4][1][0pt][0pt][0pt][\textheight]
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\title{Sample document for endnotes}
\author[1,]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
%\correspondence{Junli Liu is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology \newline e-mail: \href{mailto:keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}{keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}}
%\presentaddress{James Rowe continued from this author address\newline e-mail: James@durham.ac.uk }
\maketitle


\noindent Patterning\endnote{note1} in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).   

\begin{figure}[!t]
\caption{The sample caption\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}\endnote{figure endnote}
\end{document}
```

The below mentioned required output should be updated on printing endnote page.

[image]

The below mentioned required output needs to be updated the chapter opening page.

[image]

My two way link endnote package below mentioned

```
\usepackage{color}
\@definecounter{endnote}
\def\theendnote{\@arabic\c@endnote}

\def\@makeenmark{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{Q\@theenmark}}}
\def\makeenmark{\@makeenmark}

\def\theenmark{\@theenmark}

\newdimen\endnotesep

\def\endnote{\@ifnextchar[\@xendnote{\stepcounter{endnote}%
     \protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
     \@endnotemark\@endnotetext}}

\def\@xendnote[#1]{%
   \begingroup
     \c@endnote=#1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
   \endgroup
   \@endnotemark\@endnotetext}

%  Here begins a section of endnote code that's really different from
% the footnote code of LaTeX.

\let\@doanenote=0
\let\@endanenote=0

\newwrite\@enotes
\newif\if@enotesopen \global\@enotesopenfalse

\def\@openenotes{\immediate\openout\@enotes=\jobname.ent\relax
      \global\@enotesopentrue}

%  The stuff with \next and \meaning is a trick from the TeXbook, 382,
% there intended for setting verbatim text, but here used to avoid
% macro expansion when the footnote text is written.  \next will have
% the entire text of the footnote as one long line, which might well
% overflow limits on output line length; the business with \newlinechar
% makes every space become a newline in the \@enotes file, so that all
% of the lines wind up being quite short.

\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
     \if@enotesopen \else \@openenotes \fi
     \immediate\write\@enotes{\@doanenote{\@theenmark}}%
     \begingroup
        \def\next{#1}%
        \newlinechar='40
        \immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
     \endgroup
     \immediate\write\@enotes{\@endanenote}}

% \addtoendnotes works the way the other endnote macros probably should
% have, requiring the use of \protect for fragile commands.

\long\def\addtoendnotes#1{%
     \if@enotesopen \else \@openenotes \fi
     \begingroup
        \newlinechar='40
        \let\protect\string
        \immediate\write\@enotes{#1}%
     \endgroup}

%  End of unique endnote code

\def\endnotemark{%
   \@ifnextchar[\@xendnotemark
     {\stepcounter{endnote}%
      \protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
      \@endnotemark}}

\def\@xendnotemark[#1]{%
   \begingroup
      \c@endnote #1\relax
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
   \endgroup
   \@endnotemark}

\def\@endnotemark{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak\fi
  \makeenmark
  \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi
  \relax}

\def\endnotetext{%
     \@ifnextchar [\@xendnotenext
       {\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
    \@endnotetext}}

\def\@xendnotenext[#1]{\begingroup \c@endnote=#1\relax
   \xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}\endgroup \@endnotetext}

\def\@xendnotenext[#1]{%
  \begingroup
     \c@endnote=#1\relax
     \unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
  \endgroup
  \@endnotetext}


%  \theendnotes actually prints out the endnotes.

%  The user may want separate endnotes for each chapter, or a big
% block of them at the end of the whole document.  As it stands,
% either will work; you just say \theendnotes wherever you want the
% endnotes so far to be inserted.  However, you must add
% \setcounter{endnote}{0} after that if you want subsequent endnotes
% to start numbering at 1 again.

%  \enoteformat is provided so user can specify some special formatting
% for the endnotes.  It needs to set up the paragraph parameters, start
% the paragraph, and print the label.  The \mbox stuff in \enoteheading
% is to make and undo a dummy paragraph, to get around the games \section*
% plays with paragraph indenting and instead give us uniform
% indenting for all notes.

\def\notesname{Notes}%
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}

\def\enoteformat{\rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}

\def\enotesize{\footnotesize}

\def\theendnotes{\immediate\closeout\@enotes \global\@enotesopenfalse
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    %
    % The machinery with \@ResetGT and > here ensures that
    % \@doanenote works properly even if > is an active character
    % at the point where \theendnotes is invoked. > needs to have
    % catcode 12 when the arguments of \@doanenote are scanned, so
    % that the > in the string "macro:->" is matched.  The actual
    % footnote text is not an argument to \@doanenote, but just
    % follows it in the .ent file; so \@ResetGT can reset the
    % category code for > that should be used when processing
    % that text.  That resetting takes place within a
    % \begingroup-\endgroup block set up by \@doanenote and
    % \@endanenote, so the catcode for > is back to 12 for the
    % next note.
    %
    \edef\@tempa{`\string >}%
    \ifnum\catcode\@tempa=12%
      \let\@ResetGT\relax
    \else
      \edef\@ResetGT{\noexpand\catcode\@tempa=\the\catcode\@tempa}%
      \@makeother\>%
    \fi
    \def\@doanenote##1##2>{\def\@theenmark{##1}\par\begingroup
        \@ResetGT
        \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@endnote\endcsname\@theenmark}%
        \enoteformat}
    \def\@endanenote{\par\endgroup}%
    \enoteheading
    \enotesize
    \input{\jobname.ent}%
  \endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% hyperendnotes.sty started
\makeatletter
\newif\ifenotelinks
\newcounter{Hendnote}
% Redefining portions of endnotes-package:
\let\savedhref\href
\let\savedurl\url
\def\endnotemark{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnotemark{%
\stepcounter{endnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\@endnotemark
}%
}%
\def\@xendnotemark[#1]{%
\begingroup\c@endnote#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\endgroup
\@endnotemark
}%
\def\endnotetext{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnotenext{%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\@endnotetext
}%
}%
\def\@xendnotenext[#1]{%
\begingroup
\c@endnote=#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\endgroup
\@endnotetext
}%
\def\endnote{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnote{%
\stepcounter{endnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\@endnotemark\@endnotetext
}%
}%
\def\@xendnote[#1]{%
\begingroup
\c@endnote=#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\show\@theenvalue
\endgroup
\@endnotemark\@endnotetext
}%
\def\@endnotemark{%
\leavevmode
\ifhmode
\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak
\fi
\ifenotelinks
\expandafter\@firstofone
\else
\expandafter\@gobble
\fi
{%
\Hy@raisedlink{%
\hyper@@anchor{Hendnotepage.\@theenvalue}{\empty}%
}%
}%
\marginpar{\hyper@linkstart{link}{Hendnote.\@theenvalue}%
\makeenmark
\hyper@linkend}
\ifhmode
\spacefactor\@x@sf
\fi
\relax
}%
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
\if@enotesopen
\else
\@openenotes
\fi
\immediate\write\@enotes{%
\@doanenote{\@theenmark}{\@theenvalue}%
}%
\begingroup
\def\next{#1}%
\newlinechar='40
\immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
\endgroup
\immediate\write\@enotes{%
\@endanenote
}%
}%
\def\theendnotes{%
\immediate\closeout\@enotes
\global\@enotesopenfalse
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\edef\@tempa{`\string>}%
\ifnum\catcode\@tempa=12
\let\@ResetGT\relax
\else
\edef\@ResetGT{\noexpand\catcode\@tempa=\the\catcode\@tempa}%
\@makeother\>%
\fi
\def\@doanenote##1##2##3>{%
\def\@theenmark{##1}%
\def\@theenvalue{##2}%
\par
\smallskip %<-small vertical gap between endnotes
\begingroup
\def\href{\expandafter\savedhref}%
\def\url{\expandafter\savedurl}%
\@ResetGT
\edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@endnote\endcsname\@theenmark}%
\enoteformat
}%
\def\@endanenote{%
\par\endgroup
}%
% Redefine, how numbers are formatted in the endnotes-section:
\renewcommand*\@makeenmark{%
\hbox{\normalfont\@theenmark~}%
}%
% header of endnotes-section
\enoteheading
% font-size of endnotes
\enotesize
\input{\jobname.ent}%
\endgroup
}%
\def\enoteformat{%
\rightskip\z@
\leftskip1.8em
\parindent\z@
\leavevmode\llap{%
\setcounter{Hendnote}{\@theenvalue}%
\addtocounter{Hendnote}{-1}%
\refstepcounter{Hendnote}%
\ifenotelinks
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\fi
{\@firstofone}%
{\hyperlink{Hendnotepage.\@theenvalue}}%
{\makeenmark}%
}%
}%
% stop redefining portions of endnotes-package:
\makeatother
% Toggle switch in order to turn on/off back-links in the
% endnote-section:
\enotelinkstrue
%\enotelinksfalse
```

Please advice changing the vruler font size and the vruler should be hide on the endnote printing first page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the size of the numbers printed by the `vruler` package you need to patch the macro `\makevruler`, so add the following lines to your preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makevruler}
{\tiny}
{\small}
{}
{}
```

Change `\small` to the sizing command you like.

Then, to start the numbering from the second page, replace the following code in your MWE

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\theendnotes}\newpage
\setvruler[10pt][1][1][4][1][0pt][0pt][0pt][\textheight]
\makeatother
```

with (`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are not needed in this case):

```
% ------------- comment this at the first run -------------
\AtBeginDocument{\theendnotes\clearpage%
  \setvruler[10pt][1][1][4][1][0pt][0pt][0pt][\textheight]}
%----------------------------------------------------------
```

so to clear the page before issuing the `\vruler` command.

I've added the comments to inform people going to run the following MWE, that, at the first run those lines have to be commented, since the endnotes are not being created yet, and the file `.ent` containing them is missing.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{vruler}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makevruler}
{\tiny}
{\small}
{}
{}

% ------------- comment this at the first run -------------
\AtBeginDocument{\theendnotes\clearpage%
  \setvruler[10pt][1][1][4][1][0pt][0pt][0pt][\textheight]}
%----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}


\title{Sample document for endnotes}
\author[1,]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
%\correspondence{Junli Liu is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology \newline e-mail: \href{mailto:keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}{keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}}
%\presentaddress{James Rowe continued from this author address\newline e-mail: James@durham.ac.uk }
\maketitle


\noindent Patterning\endnote{note1} in Arabidopsis root development
is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the
root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression
of speciÞc genes. This auxin gradient has been hypothesized to be sink-driven (Friml et al., 2002) and com- putational modeling suggests that auxin efßux carrier activity may be sufÞcient to generate the gradient in the absence of auxin biosynthesis in the root (Grieneisen et al., 2007; Wabnik et al., 2010). However, other experimental studies show that local auxin biosynthesis modulates gradient- directed planar polarity in Arabidopsis, and a local source of auxin biosynthesis contributes to auxin gradient homeostasis (Ikeda et al., 2009). Thus genetic studies show that auxin biosynthesis (Ikeda et al., 2009; Normanly, 2010; Zhao, 2010), the AUX1/LAX inßux carriers (Swarup et al., 2005, 2008; Jones et al., 2008; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010), and the PIN auxin efux carri- ers (Petr‡sek et al., 2006; Grieneisen et al., 2007; Krupinski and Jonsson, 2010; Mironova et al., 2010) all play important roles in the formation of auxin gradients. In addition, experimental evidence shows that, in root devel- opment, hormones and the associated regulatory and target genes form a network, in which relevant genes regulate hormone activ- ities and hormones regulate gene expression. For example, ethy- lene promotes auxin ßux in the root, in a process dependent on the POLARIS (PLS) peptide (Ruzicka et al., 2007; Swarup et al., 2007; Liu et al., 2010a). Furthermore, PIN levels are positively reg- ulated by ethylene and auxin in Arabidopsis roots (Ruzicka et al., 2007). Interestingly, cytokinin can negatively regulate PIN lev- els (Ruzicka et al., 2009), while repressing auxin biosynthesis and promoting ethylene responses (Nordstrom et al., 2004; Chandler, 2009; Liu et al., 2010a). Cytokinin also has the capacity to mod- ulate auxin transport, by transcriptional regulation of the PIN genes (Ruzicka et al., 2009).

\begin{figure}[!t]
\caption{The sample caption\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}\endnote{figure endnote}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I got the solution